# Property 'item' not found on object

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I'm setting up a view controller in my iOS app to put an item into an array when a submit button is pressed. However, I'm receiving an error that the 'item' property isn't found in the object. I suspect this is because 'item' is defined in a different implementation, XYZMatchCenterViewController.m, but I'm not sure how to make it so that XYZBuyViewController.m makes use of it as well.

XYZBuyViewController.m:

```
#import "XYZBuyViewController.h"

@interface XYZBuyViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *itemName;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *submitButton;

@end

@implementation XYZBuyViewController


- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if (sender != self.submitButton) return;
    if (self.itemName.text.length > 0) {
        self.Item = [[XYZItem alloc] init];
        self.Item.itemName = self.itemName.text;
    }
}


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

XYZMatchCenterViewController.m:

```
#import "XYZMatchCenterViewController.h"
#import "XYZItem.h"

@interface XYZMatchCenterViewController ()

@property NSMutableArray *items;

@end

@implementation XYZMatchCenterViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return [self.items count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 3;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ListPrototypeCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    XYZItem *Item = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = Item.itemName;

    return cell;
}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a story board-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}

 */

@end
```

Comment: have you tried adding the line #import "XYZItem.h"?

Comment: Yeah, doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared an `item` property at all. You have a property called `items`—perhaps you mean that.

Comment: I was referring to the 
`XYZItem *Item = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = Item.itemName;` 

that appears in MatchCenterViewController.